# Could the padlock icon shown in the Safari address bar in macOS, be moved or removed?

Tags: macos, safari

The address bar in Safari for macOS shows a padlock icon just left of the current website address. Is it possible to move or remove it altogether?

It's shown almost in the middle of the address bar, and I keep hitting it when I just want to enter new text in the address bar.

Comment: I do the same thing. Constantly clicking the padlock icon, which spawns an alert, when I just mean to click the address bar and enter a new address. Very annoying.

Comment: You can submit an enhancement request for Safari here (as I just did): https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Comment: I thought it was just me. This is a mistake in UX design from Apple. So frustrating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The padlock (lock) icon shown in the Safari address bar cannot be moved or remove. But if it's getting in the way, you can try one of the following approaches.

1. Instead of clicking using Mouse/Trackpad, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to move focus to the address bar. Doing so also selects the current website address, so you can immediately start typing to enter new website address or search query.
2. You may consider enabling Show full website address setting under Advanced tab of Safari preferences. This would show the full address of the current webpage and may also move the padlock towards left in the Smart Search Field/Safari Address Bar thereby reducing the possibility of accidental click.

**P.S.**: The lock icon is shown in the address bar (officially named the Smart Search Field) for a good reason. You should be cautious when the padlock icon is missing. To learn more, refer to this official document from Safari guide from Apple:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/sfri40697/mac

Comment: I realise this sounds trite and still, it's true. Telling yourself to "avoid the padlock…" will not work. Telling yourself to "click in the clear space at left or right of the address bar…" will work, even it takes a few days to kick in.